# Validation of Inclusion using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add validation of inclusion using jQuery.

For Example : `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

Now, suppose my value is `'A'`, then how can I check using jQuery so that when `'A'` is included in above array.

If value is include in Array then `return true;` otherwise `return false;`

Please Help Me, Thanks In Advance.

Comment: [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is the jQuery way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
console.log($.inArray('A',['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) > -1) //true
```

Please read here to know more about **[$.inArray(value, array)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/p7Lc4/)

Comment: no.. it returns the index of the element if found or -1 if not found

Comment: **$.inArray(array,value)** should be `$.inArray(value,array)`

Comment: @Manwal Please have a careful look over the post.. :)

Comment: Your syntax is ok @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but link should be corrected

Comment: @Manwal Sharp eyes.. :)